# Create an observablecollection from a living dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a `Dictionary<string, MyClass>` and I need to expose its values to the UI (WPF application). So I tried to create an ObservableCollection:

`this.MyList = new ObservableCollection(this.MyDictionary.Values)`

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) : The returned `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` is not a static copy; instead, the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` refers back to the values in the original `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Therefore, changes to the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` continue to be reflected in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection`.

But when I add new items in my dictionary, the changes are not reflected in my observable collection.

I'm afraid I cannot do what I want but may be there is a trick that I do not know.

---

**Solution**

While the accepted answer answered the question, which is, I can't do what I want with the native API, here is how I built my own object:

```
private class LivingHashedCollection<T>
{
    private HashSet<T> _set;
    private ObservableCollection<T> _list;

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> Values { get; private set; }

    public LivingHashedCollection()
    {
        _set = new HashSet<T>();
        _list = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        this.Values = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>(_list);
    }

    public void AddValues(ICollection<T> values)
    {
        foreach (var val in values)
        {
            if (!_set.Contains(val))
            {
                _set.Add(val);
                _list.Add(val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I finally chose the HashSet instead of the Dictionary for generic purpose. Obviously, this implementation can be improved (can implement IEnumerable, ICollection, for example), but the basis is here !

Comment: Try to 'refresh' it with `RaisePropertyChanged`

Comment: no matter MSDN is correct or not, why do you rely on that, do you think the performance is better if you do not copy the values once?

Comment: `Values` indeed refer back to the values of dictionary, but `ObservableCollection` will copy all values you pass to constructor to it's own internal list. From this point it is completely disconnected from original collection.

Comment: I thought `ObservableCollection` was a wrapper around the specified list like the `ReadOnlyCollection`. But you are right, the ObservableCollection just copies the values into its own internal list... I guess this kind of class does not exists ?

Comment: @Evk I think your comment is clearer than my answer, I'm going to delete it and you may post it as an answer

Comment: "I guess this kind of class does not exists ?" Correct. You should add the object directly to the ObservableCollection. Adding to the dictionary that was passed to the constructor when the ObservableCollection was created doesn't affect the ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` will always make a copy of a list you pass to the constructor. That's done for several reasons, but the main one (I think) is that `ObservableCollection` main purpose is track changes to it's contents, but it has no way to track changes to external collection you pass to it's constructor, so changes to it will go unnoticed (without raising `CollectionChanged` event).